# Jquery datepicker UI

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker

Hi I am struggling to get this Date/Calendar Jquery UI to work in Angularjs (as a beginner).
The UI widget is not appearing and the error message I am getting is:

**TypeError: elem.datepicker is not a function**

I have this linked to jquery

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

This is my html view:

```
<div ng-controller="DateCtrl">
    <h1> Date: {{date | date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}</h1>
    <input type="text" ng-model="date" datepicker />
</div>
```

This is my controller and directive:

```
.controller('DateCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.date = new Date();
})
.directive('datepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            elem.datepicker({
                dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: as a suggestion rather than an answer, have you considered using AngularUI's datepicker (jqueryUI built for angular) https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code and its working for me with the following:

Make sure scripts in correct order:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

My `app.js`:

```
// Where 'app' is whatever you're using to define ng-app
// e.g. <body ng-app="app">
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('DateCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.date = new Date();
});

 app.directive('datepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            elem.datepicker({
                dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

As another suggestion I would recommend that it might be easier to use [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Little changes required in your directive:

```
  .directive("datepicker", function () {
      return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          var updateModel = function (date) {
            scope.$apply(function () {
              ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
            });
          };
          var options = {
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            onSelect: function (date) {
              updateModel(date);
            }
          };
          elem.datepicker(options);
        }
      }
    });
```